# Stepwise Regression - when will bi-direction give different results?

Tags: r, regression, stepwise-regression

There is forward selection and backward elimination, and in both cases we can not only add or subtract variables, but also do both. My question is under which circumstances would the `direction="both"` give a different result than either forward or backward?

```
auto.both <- step(min.model, direction="both", scope=list(lower=min.model, upper=max.model))
```

It would need to e.g., add variables and then at one point remove a variable already added. Is it because of some correlation structure in the data? Is it possible to create a dataset that would behave like this, or any known dataset behaves like this?

Comment: It's probably not hard to generate a dataset that does this, simply by simulating datasets and running stepwise until we find something. What I find more interesting: why look at stepwise regression in the first place? Its issues are well known.

Comment: I am guessing that a data set with colinear variables would behave like this. But, as @StephanKolassa said, why do this in the first place?

Comment: @PeterFlom Thanks - that seemed to work. `set.seed(247)
n=50
x1 = rnorm(n)
x2 = rnorm(n)
x3 = x1 + x2 + rnorm(n, sd=0.2)
x4 = x3 + rnorm(n)
y = x1 + x2 + x3 - x4 -1 + rnorm(n, sd=1)

lm0 = lm(y~1)
lm1 = lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4)
step(lm0, scope = list(lower = lm0, upper = lm1), direction = "both", k = 1)`